# Selecting an AMI based on a logical argument

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

At the moment my terraform creates an instance based on the AMI hardcoded into the environment. Problem I have is there's three possible use cases for this particular resource. Is it possible to write this into terraform so that if I were to enter a variable 'Dev' one AMI would be selected, and 'Prod' another AMI would be selected?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to have an input variable specifying an environment and then select a different value based on environment.

Let's first define the variable, so we can see what we're talking about:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = string

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["Dev", "Prod"], var.environment)
    error_message = "Environment must be either 'Dev' or 'Prod'."
  }
}
```

With that defined, our problem is to look up a value based on a given string. A typical way to do that is to define a map value that specifies an output value for each valid input value, and in Terraform we can declare such a thing as a local value:

```
locals {
  ami_ids = tomap({
    Dev  = "ami-abc123"
    Prod = "ami-xyz789"
  })
}
```

Now when you need to refer to the AMI ID corresponding to the specified environment, you can use the index syntax to access the appropriate element by the environment key:

```
  ami = local.ami_ids[var.environment]
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to answer this in such a comprehensive manner. Hopefully this will make life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a variable as env
2. Based on the value override the variable value

   var.env != "dev" ? var.env : "dev ami "
3. Use the variable as ami in resource